# install podcast generator on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, generator, hosting, podcast

I have a regular web hosting account with an online company winch I'm using to publish my podcast using podcast generator, since I know that we are able to host a static website on Amazon S3, I was thinking that: podcast generator does not use a database so it could also be host just like a static website (I could be wrong!) now is it possible to upload all the files from the podcast generator zip folder to the Amazon S3 and launch it as I normal would? To summarize I want my website build from podcast generator to be on Amazon cloud Hosting service instead of conventional web hosting, can it be done and how?

now this is what I've done:
on Amazon S3 /website/Index Document: I've placed index.php
well what had happened was the index.php file just display on the page.

Can abyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Podcast Generator on Amazon S3 because Amazon S3 [just allows to host static websites and does not support server-side scripting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) (such as PHP).
Podcast Generator is written in PHP and a webserver with PHP support is the minimun requirement to run it.

Comment: I have an ec2 instance and want to use an s3 bucket instead of the "media" folder on my instance. Has anybody done that?